# How to build Windows phone 10 app with Ionics

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, windows-10-mobile

I am trying to develop Ionic application for Windows 10 Phone by referring Ionics documentation. This document has commands to build app for iOS and Android. But it does not specify how to build the project for Windows 10 Phone. 
I also tried using Visual Studio 2015, but that too does not work.
Someone please provide proper steps to build and run the app on Windows 10 Phone. I am using Lumia 950.

Comment: On the bottom of this page http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/platform-setup/windows-setup.html there is some information about Windows platforms. Have you gone through those steps?

Comment: Yes we tried that. But we get error: "No Valid MSBuild for selected target"

Comment: Did it worked finally?